# shiny updateSelectInput not showing values drop down menu blank

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, ggplot2, shiny, rworldmap

I created a second field of input "Select a country" for country plots based on a prior input field of "Select a region" from the side panel.

I used the "country" column of the designated data table as the names that will appear after each "region" (also a column) is selected, with updateSelectInput.

For some reason it works in one of the tabs I have created called "gender", which has exactly the same format except that the data table used is different. I pretty much copied and pasted the chunk of the codes in the "gender" tab in the tab "highest education." But for the "highest education" tab, when I select a particular region, the drop-down menu for "Select a country" is blank, although I can see that it loads the plot of the first country supposedly on that list of that region.

I've playing around with the types of variable "country", switching between factor and character. Right now the codes works for "gender" tab only. I'm at my wit's end.

Can someone spot what's wrong with my code?

The dataset look like this:

```
iso3  region   participation   country       male     female    lower class    
ALB   region2     0.5262631    Albania    0.5834176  0.4702970   0.4285714               
AND   region1     0.6699900    Andorra    0.7236581  0.6160000   0.4117647               
ARG   region4     0.2857675    Argentina  0.3109277  0.2631020   0.2270694
```

The data set for the "gender tab" is this:

```
data.frame':    85 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ region : Factor w/ 7 levels "region1","region2",..: 2 1 4 2 7 3 5 3 2 2 ...
 $ country: Factor w/ 85 levels "Albania","Algeria",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 13 8 12 10 ...
 $ male   : num  0.58 0.72 0.31 1 0.67 0.45 0.41 0.62 0.21 0.53 ...
 $ female : num  0.47 0.62 0.26 1 0.67 0.4 0.24 0.38 0.16 0.35 ...
```

The data set for the highest education tab is this:

```
'data.frame':   85 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ region               : Factor w/ 7 levels "region1","region2",..: 2 1 4 2 7 3 5 3 2 2 
 $ country              : Factor w/ 85 levels "Albania","Algeria",..: 1 3 4 5 6 7 13 8 
 $ Primary              : num  0.456 0.525 0.215 1 0.519 ...
 $ Secondary.incomplete : num  0.489 0.614 0.337 0.995 0.727 ...
 $ Secondary.vocational : num  0.561 0.681 0.324 1 0.768 ...
 $ Secondary.preparatory: num  0.583 0.632 0.492 0.998 0.793 ...
 $ Tertiary.incomplete  : num  0.696 0.732 0.545 0.981 0.802 ...
 $ Tertiary             : num  0.728 0.833 0.625 0.997 0.854 ...
```

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

dataset <- wvs_c

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Membership in Associations in 85 countries using World Values Survey,   
     1981-2007"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("region", "Select a region:",
            list("All World"= "the world",
                 "North America & Western Europe"="region1",
                 "Central Europe"="region2",
                 "Asia"="region3",
                 "Latina America & Caribbean"="region4",
                 "Sub-Saharan Africa"="region5",
                 "Middle East & Northern Africa"="region6",
                 "Oceania"="region7"),
                  selected= "the World" )
   ),


  mainPanel(
    h4("testing"),

    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'dataset',
      tabPanel('Map', plotOutput("map")
           , helpText("Probability of being a member of an association, types of 
association included are
           sports, arts, labor, politics, environment, women's rights, human rights,
           charity, and other.")),

  tabPanel('Gender', dataTableOutput('mytable'),
           selectInput('country', 'Select a Country:', 
                       names(wvs_c$country), selected=names(wvs_c$country)[1]),
           plotOutput("myplot")
           ),

  tabPanel('Highest education attained', dataTableOutput('mytable1'),
           selectInput('country', 'Select a Country:', 
                       names(wvs_c$country), selected=names(wvs_c$country)[1]),
           plotOutput("myplot1")
           )
),

p("Above is a graphical representation of rate of being an associational member.")


)

)))
```

### server.R

```
library(rworldmap)
library(plyr)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

wvs_c <- read.csv("./wvs_c") 

wvs_c <- wvs_c[, -1]


shinyServer(function(input,output,session) {

   gender <- wvs_c[,c(2, 4:6)]
   highested <- wvs_c[,c(2, 4, 12:17)]

   colnames(highested) <- c("region", "country", "Primary", "Secondary.incomplete", 
                            "Secondary.vocational","Secondary.preparatory", 
                            "Tertiary.incomplete", "Tertiary")


 # Create a second field of input "Select a country" based on the first input field 
 "Select a region"

  observe({
    region = input$region
    updateSelectInput(session, "country", 
    choices = levels(as.factor(as.character(wvs_c$country[wvs_c$region==region]))),   
    selected = levels(as.factor(as.character(wvs_c$country[wvs_c$region==region])))[1]
      )
    })

# Create charts for each country's gender breakdown

  selectedPlot <- reactive({
     if (input$region == "the world") {

   #for regional average of gender
   test<- aggregate(gender[, c("male", "female")],  by = 
          list(as.character(gender$region)), function(x) c(mean=mean(x)))
   colnames(test)[1] <- "region"
   test2 <- melt(test[,c('region','male','female')],id.vars = 1)

  ## codes for ggplot using "test2", works

    } else {
      region = input$region
      country = input$country

      cbbPalette <- c("#01DFD7", "#F78181")

      x <- gender[(gender$country== country),]
      x <- melt(x[,c('country','male','female')], id.vars = 1)
      x1 <- ggplot(data=x, aes(x=variable, y=value)) 
      x1 <- x1 + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette)
      x1 <- x1 + labs(y = 'Percent of members', x = '') + theme(axis.text.x = 
      element_blank()) + ylim(0, 1) + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
      x1

      }
      })

output$myplot = renderPlot({
        selectedPlot()
      }
      )

   # Create charts for each country's educational level breakdown

      selectedPlot1 <- reactive({
        if (input$region == "the world") {

          test3 <- aggregate(highested_data[, c('Primary', 'Secondary.incomplete', 
         'Secondary.vocational','Secondary.preparatory', 'Tertiary.incomplete',       
          'Tertiary')], by = list(as.character(highested_data$region)), function(x)  
          c(mean=mean(x)))
          colnames(test3)[1] <- "region"

          test3 <- melt(test3[, c
              ('region','Primary','Secondary.incomplete','Secondary.vocational'
                      ,'Secondary.preparatory','Tertiary.incomplete','Tertiary')], 
                      id.vars = 1)

## codes for ggplot using "test3", works

        } else {
          region = input$region
          country = input$country

           cbbPalette1 <- c("#F7BE81", "#F79F81", "#82FA58", "#04B486", "#00BFFF", 
                            "#01A9DB")

            y <- highested[(highested$country == country),]

            y <-melt(y[,   
                c('country','Primary','Secondary.incomplete','Secondary.vocational'
               ,'Secondary.preparatory','Tertiary.incomplete','Tertiary')], id.vars = 1)

            y1 <- ggplot(data=y, aes(x=variable, y=value)) 
            y1 <- y1 + geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position="dodge", stat="identity") 
                  + scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette1)
            y1 <- y1 + labs(y = 'Percent of members', x = '') + theme(axis.text.x =   
            element_blank()) + ylim(0, 1) +
            theme(legend.title=element_blank())
            y1

          } 
          })

    output$myplot1 = renderPlot({
      selectedPlot1()
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else pointed out my problem:

I have only one SelectInput field for country but I have two tabs. It confuses the browser.
So I created a separate chuck codes specifying the input in the server.R and use a different inputID for the ui.R

ui.R

```
tabPanel('Highest education attained', dataTableOutput('mytable1'),
           selectInput('country2', 'Select a Country:', 
                       names(wvs_c$country), selected=names(wvs_c$country)[1]),
           plotOutput("myplot1")
           )
```

server.R

```
observe({
  region = input$region
  updateSelectInput(session, "country2",
                choices =     
levels(as.factor(as.character(wvs_c$country[wvs_c$region==region]))), selected = 
levels(as.factor(as.character(wvs_c$country[wvs_c$region==region])))[1]
  )
})

 # then in the codes for highest education country plot   
....
} else {
  region = input$region
  country = input$country2
```